# Running CakePHP validation messages through a wrapper method

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using a new localization system on our site that requires all the displayed strings to be run through the SDK so all can be modified and localized on the go remotely. My only issue is that I am so far unable to run validation messages through this system as they are defined in the model. Is there any option how to do this for all, preferably in one go, without having to re-do the entire model system?

I am using following:

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Name of the application can not be empty',
        ),
    ),
);
```

and would like to achieve something like this (which obviously wouldn't work):

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => MyLocalizationMethod('Name of the application can not be empty'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: CakePHP will assume any validation string requires localisation, as such these can be extracted to PO files when you run the I18n shell tool. You might want to explore this before reinventing the wheel. If you can give us some more details of the SDK you're referring to, I'm sure someone can help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case dont set the messages in the `$validate`. Rather define the `__construct()` and inside the `__construct()` set the messages. Try with -

```
$this->Model->validationErrors['name']['notEmpty'] = MyLocalizationMethod("time is less than 30");
```

Comment: Yeah, I realize that, I was just hoping for an easier approach where I could modify this somehow globally without having to change every model ... and there is huge amount of them :(

Comment: The whole Model::validate array could be set within the constructor which might make the code more readable and easier to maintain. Otherwise, every time the models validate property is updated you'd need to remember to also update the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP is already setup to easily allow for localisation of your validation error messages.

All you need to do is [generate a POT file](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html) that can then be translated for each localisation:-

```
./Console/cake i18n extract
```

There are many free POT file editors out there. Personally, I use [poedit](http://poedit.net/).

You therefore shouldn't need to edit your models. The setup for localisation has already been done just be writing validation rules in your models.

Otherwise, I'd be inclined to use sgt Bose's answer, but set the entire `Model::validate` array in the constructor; it will make the code more readable and easier to maintain.